# Access Report: Page header on second page on per detail

Tags: ms-access, ms-access-2007, vba

I want to display a header only on the second page and beyond but PER record. The first page of the new detail should not have the page header visible.

Originally I had the following code

```
Private Sub PageHeaderSection_Format(Cancel As Integer, FormatCount As Integer)
    Me.PageHeaderSection.Visible = Not (Me.Page = 1)
End Sub
```

It displays the header on everyother page except the first.

I want the header to be visible after the first page (but not including the first page) for each group.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I created this simple sub that seems to do the trick. Basically, for each page, it checks if the group is the same as before. If it is different it assumes that it is the first page of the group and doesn't display the header.

```
'At the top of the module window I created a "Module-Level Variables".
Dim current_group As Integer
Dim temp_group As Integer

Private Sub PageHeaderSection_Format(Cancel As Integer, FormatCount As Integer)

    current_group = Int(Me.MyGroupID)

    If current_group = temp_inst Then
        Me.PageHeaderSection.Visible = True
    Else
        Me.PageHeaderSection.Visible = False
    End If

    temp_group = current_group    
End Sub
```

Answer (score 6):

Way too complicated.

The first one was better!

```
Private Sub PageHeaderSection_Format(Cancel As Integer, FormatCount As Integer)

    Me.PageHeaderSection.Visible = Not (Me.Page = 1)
    Debug.Print "Page " & Me.Page & " Visible = " & Not (Me.Page = 1)

End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

In the Sorting and Grouping for the report, add the field that identifies the record and that you want to group on. In the OnFormat event of that section header, do the same thing you're doing above: RecordHeader.Visible=(Me.Page<>1)

Comment: When you say "PER record", what identifies each record? And reading a bit more closely, if record 10 starts on page 15, are you trying to not show the header for that record on page 15 but show the header on page 16?

Comment: Well, I added a group. That's exactly what I want to do.